# How to disable TLS/SSL support for 3DES cipher suite?

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2, 3des

I have launched a server and during penetration testing, i found that my server is vulnerable to SWEET32 attack as it has weak cipher how do i disable the support for TLS/SSL for 3DES cipher suite as it is now vulnerable to openssl,SSH and openVPN attack.

Comment: The details depend on the type of server. There is no generic server with a generic configuration.

Comment: i want to remove the cipher from AWS ec2 linux 2

Comment: *"AWS ec2 linux 2"* is an OS image and not a specific server. The thing you are looking for is something like Apache, nginx etc. As for proper server configuration see [Mozilla recommendation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS). Also see [AWS documentation about this topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html#ssl-test-alami)

Comment: The penetration test specifies for ssh port, there is no server running, only inbound traffic is to port 22. You can read more about the cipher attack here https://sweet32.info

Comment: I know the attack. But I have  practically no useful information about your server and the penetration test since you don't provide sufficient details. And you explicitly ask for disabling support in SSL/TLS - SSH is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use IISCrypto if it is a Windows server. Juts run it, untick the 3DES cipher suites on the first page and cipher suites page / TAB and reboot.